# Storage trigger function with Cloud Run

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I have written a Cloud Storage trigger in python. Due to conflicts in the version of certain packages, I need a way to add a timeseries model to the Cloud Storage trigger function.

Is it possible to add a docker image in a cloud storage trigger function written in python? The tutorials state that the containers can be triggered using service URL which is basically like a HTTP trigger. Can be it be a Cloud Storage trigger?

Answer (score 4):

Cloud Functions doesn't support the deployment of custom docker images.  Cloud Functions will internally build a docker image based on the code you deploy, and you can't influence how that image is built.

If you want to handle a Cloud Storage event in a docker image, you will have to do something like this:

- Write a Storage trigger which forwards the event data to a Cloud Run endpoint
- Build and deploy a docker image to Cloud Run which receives the event data from the function and does what you want

Or perhaps you just want to deploy a [Cloud Run image that subscribes to a pubsub topic](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/pubsub-push) that delivers the [Cloud Storage pubsub notification events](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) to process.